# I'm programming a game interface in vb6 where we can enter the direction and the location changes and game continues

Tags: vb6

I am trying to make a text game where the user is on a default location in start then he can choose which direction to move and new location comes. the objective is to find the 3 crystals in 3 different location and go to the last location for which you need 3 crystals to go in.

Please refer to the map attached for better understanding(we start at the enchanted forest)

My problem is at the start if I go from enchanted forest to west (location2) everything works perfect there. when I come back from there i.e east from location2 it comes back to enchanted forest. Meanwhile NOW if I go north/south/east/west it stays at the same position. 
also if from the start i go directly to north/south/east it goes there but after that anywhere i try to move it does not move(stays at same position) also the if command giving the crystal won't work aswell
it's like no if command works once i move north/south/east from starting location
or comeback from west

P.S: I added a little extra code trying to fix the problem. Also I am just a new programmer so bear with me :|

[Map in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mddwW.jpg)
`Private Sub Command1_Click()`

```
  `Dim RunGame, Location1, Location2, Location3,` Location4,Location5,Location6, Location7, Location8, Location9, CurrentLocation As String
   Dim Crystal As Integer
   Crystal = 0
   RunGame = ""
   Location1 = "Enchanted Forest"
   Location2 = "Bridge of Death"
   Location3 = "Wizard's Castle"
   Location4 = "Marsh of the Undead"
   Location5 = "Sands of Quick"
   Location6 = "Swamps of despair"
   Location7 = "Elven Waterfall"
   Location8 = "Vampire Cove"
   Location9 = "Werewolf Hills"
   CurrentLocation = Location1


   Do
       Do
    RunGame = UCase(InputBox("In Which direction do you want to go next?"))
    If (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "QUIT") Then
        Print "True"
    Else
        MsgBox ("Invalid Entry. Please Re-try!")
    End If
    If RunGame = "QUIT" Then
        MsgBox ("Game is Ending. GoodBye!")
        End
    End If
Loop Until (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "QUIT")
    Do
        If CurrentLocation = Location1 And RunGame = "NORTH" Then CurrentLocation = Location4
        If CurrentLocation = Location1 And RunGame = "SOUTH" Then CurrentLocation = Location8
        If CurrentLocation = Location1 And RunGame = "WEST" Then CurrentLocation = Location2
        If CurrentLocation = Location1 And RunGame = "EAST" Then CurrentLocation = Location6
        Print "CurrentLocation is: "; CurrentLocation
        Do
            RunGame = UCase(InputBox("In Which direction do you want to go next?"))
            If (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "QUIT") Then
                 Print "True"
            Else
                MsgBox ("Invalid Entry. Please Re-try!")
            End If
            If RunGame = "QUIT" Then
                MsgBox ("Game is Ending. GoodBye!")
                End
            End If
        Loop Until (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "QUIT")
    Loop Until (CurrentLocation = Location2 Or CurrentLocation = Location4 Or CurrentLocation = Location6 Or CurrentLocation = Location8)
    '
    Do
        If CurrentLocation = Location2 And RunGame = "EAST" Then CurrentLocation = Location1
        If CurrentLocation = Location2 And (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH") Then MsgBox ("Empty Space")
        If CurrentLocation = Location2 And Crystal < 3 And RunGame = "WEST" Then
            CurrentLocation = Location2
            Print "Sorry you Don't have enough crystals to pass through here"
        End If
        Print "CurrentLocation is: "; CurrentLocation
        Do
            RunGame = UCase(InputBox("In Which direction do you want to go next?"))
            If (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "QUIT") Then
                 Print "True"
            Else
                MsgBox ("Invalid Entry. Please Re-try!")
            End If
            If RunGame = "QUIT" Then
                MsgBox ("Game is Ending. GoodBye!")
                End
            End If
        Loop Until (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "QUIT")
        If CurrentLocation = Location2 And Crystal >= 3 And RunGame = "WEST" Then
            CurrentLocation = Location3
            Print "Congratulations! The  Wizard have been defeated and The Prince has been rescued. You have finished the game!"
        End If
    Loop Until (CurrentLocation = Location1 Or CurrentLocation = Location3)
    '
    Do
        If CurrentLocation = Location4 Then
            Print "What's that shiny little thing? Wait It's a crystal. Obtained a crystal"
        End If
        If CurrentLocation = Location4 And RunGame = "EAST" Then
            CurrentLocation = Location4
            Print "You struggle helplessly as the quick sand sucks you in!"
        End If
        If CurrentLocation = Location4 And (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "WEST") Then MsgBox ("Empty Space")
        If CurrentLocation = Location4 And RunGame = "SOUTH" Then CurrentLocation = Location1
        Print "CurrentLocation is: "; CurrentLocation
        Do
            RunGame = UCase(InputBox("In Which direction do you want to go next?"))
            If (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "QUIT") Then
                 Print "True"
            Else
                MsgBox ("Invalid Entry. Please Re-try!")
            End If
            If RunGame = "QUIT" Then
                MsgBox ("Game is Ending. GoodBye!")
                End
            End If
        Loop Until (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "QUIT")
    Loop Until (CurrentLocation = Location1)
    '
    Do
        If CurrentLocation = Location6 And RunGame = "EAST" Then MsgBox ("Empty Space")
        If CurrentLocation = Location6 And RunGame = "NORTH" Then
            CurrentLocation = Location6
            Print "You struggle helplessly as the quick sand sucks you in!"
        End If
        If CurrentLocation = Location6 And RunGame = "WEST" Then CurrentLocation = Location1
        Print "CurrentLocation is: "; CurrentLocation
        Do
            RunGame = UCase(InputBox("In Which direction do you want to go next?"))
            If (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "QUIT") Then
                 Print "True"
            Else
                MsgBox ("Invalid Entry. Please Re-try!")
            End If
            If RunGame = "QUIT" Then
                MsgBox ("Game is Ending. GoodBye!")
                End
            End If
        Loop Until (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "QUIT")
    Loop Until (CurrentLocation = Location1 Or CurrentLocation = Location7)
    '
    Do
        If CurrentLocation = Location7 Then
            Print "What's that shiny little thing? Wait, It's a crystal. Obtained a crystal"
        End If
        If CurrentLocation = Location7 And RunGame = "NORTH" Then CurrentLocation = Location6
        If CurrentLocation = Location7 And (RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST") Then MsgBox ("Empty Space")
        Print "CurrentLocation is: "; CurrentLocation
        Do
            RunGame = UCase(InputBox("In Which direction do you want to go next?"))
            If (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "QUIT") Then
                 Print "True"
            Else
                MsgBox ("Invalid Entry. Please Re-try!")
            End If
            If RunGame = "QUIT" Then
                MsgBox ("Game is Ending. GoodBye!")
                End
            End If
        Loop Until (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "QUIT")
    Loop Until (CurrentLocation = Location6)
    '
    Do
        If CurrentLocation = Location8 And RunGame = "NORTH" Then CurrentLocation = Location1
        If CurrentLocation = Location8 And (RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST") Then MsgBox ("Empty Space")
        If CurrentLocation = Location8 And RunGame = "SOUTH" Then CurrentLocation = Location9
        Print "CurrentLocation is: "; CurrentLocation
        Do
            RunGame = UCase(InputBox("In Which direction do you want to go next?"))
            If (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "QUIT") Then
                 Print "True"
            Else
                MsgBox ("Invalid Entry. Please Re-try!")
            End If
            If RunGame = "QUIT" Then
                MsgBox ("Game is Ending. GoodBye!")
                End
            End If
        Loop Until (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "QUIT")
    Loop Until (CurrentLocation = Location1 Or CurrentLocation = Location9)
    '
    Do
        If CurrentLocation = Location9 Then
            Print "What's that shiny little thing? Wait, It's a crystal. Obtained a crystal"
        End If
        If CurrentLocation = Location9 And RunGame = "NORTH" Then CurrentLocation = Location8
        If CurrentLocation = Location9 And (RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST") Then MsgBox ("Empty Space")
        Print "CurrentLocation is: "; CurrentLocation
        Do
            RunGame = UCase(InputBox("In Which direction do you want to go next?"))
            If (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "QUIT") Then
                 Print "True"
            Else
                MsgBox ("Invalid Entry. Please Re-try!")
            End If
            If RunGame = "QUIT" Then
                MsgBox ("Game is Ending. GoodBye!")
                End
            End If
        Loop Until (RunGame = "NORTH" Or RunGame = "SOUTH" Or RunGame = "EAST" Or RunGame = "WEST" Or RunGame = "QUIT")
    Loop Until (CurrentLocation = Location8)
    '
    Loop Until RunGame = "QUIT"
    End Sub
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with answering your question. Just some advice.  If you are starting out programming now, please , please , please don't start with VB6.  While it is a programming language, it is a bad example of one and will drive you to tears.  There are many paid for and free windows based programming languages you would do much better to teach yourself.  C# or VB.NET on the paid side, python, go, ruby, php, javascript on the free side.  Please don't waste your time and effort on VB 6.

Comment: I see. I am just doing VB6 for my school (as it doesn't teach others) and examination requires vb6 or python. I'll switch to python in college next year. iA. IA=hopefully.

Comment: Ok.  Maybe teach yourself go or php or javascript on the side. Good Luck.

Comment: Planning on doing that. Thanks a lot for your concern :)

Comment: See my answer below for the other side of Toby's argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should use a two-dimensional array.  Suppose you have sixteen locations in a 4x4 matrix, each with a name.  Create an array so:

```
Dim locations(3,3) as Integer
```

Set the values of the array to their location names:

```
locations(0,0) = "Enchanted Forest"
...etc.
```

Now, create variables to hold current locations:

```
Dim cLocX as Integer, cLocY as Integer
```

To get the name of the current location in a message box:

```
MsgBox locations(cLocX, cLocY)
```

So.  To move north, subtract 1 from cLocY, to move south, add 1 to cLocY, to move east, add 1 to cLocX, and to move west, add 1 to cLocX.  Add some sort of message to say that you're at the edge of the map if you try to move north when cLocY is 0, and so on.

With all that, you should be able to create a form with buttons to move in each direction, and another button to message you what the current location is.  That will give you the foundation on which you can build what you want.

p.s. While I sympathize with Toby Allen's POV, I don't entirely agree with it. I have personally shed nary a tear while using VB6, and have written some sophisticated programs that are in production to this day, 15 years after they were written.  (Of course, I was already a programming expert before I picked it up, and I took a few classes to make sure I did things the right way from the beginning.)  It isn't a bad example of a programming language, but it IS a programming language that will cheerfully let you write terrible code.  However, it will let you write really solid code, too, and quickly.

It doesn't really matter what language you use to learn programming; the concepts you pick up are transferable to other languages.  (That said, I personally wouldn't put VB6 in a school curriculum any more; I'd use Java instead.)  However, once you get more advanced, you will probably want to move to a language that is a bit lower level than VB6.  C++ is the most popular language with game developers, because it has a good mix of object oriented capability and ways to go low level to streamline code and improve performance.  However, if you want to find just any sort of work, go with Java, along with javascript and jquery.  [Here's](http://www.codingdojo.com/blog/9-most-in-demand-programming-languages-of-2016/) an article about the most in-demand programming languages.